# Pre-fill with the id of an entity

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

How can I pre-fill a new content with an entity relationship that I know the id? I know the item is, let's say 1234, but if I use this number like that :

`@Edit.Toolbar(actions: "new", contentType: "NewsItem", prefill = new { Category = 1234 } )`

It doesn't work. When I implement the code above, the form for a new item shows up but instead of having the correct item selected, I have `(item not found)`. Obviously, my argument is not correct. So, how do I code this argument?

I also tried

`Category = {1234}
Category = new {(1234}}
Category = "1234"`

But nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're working on enhancing this, but as of now, you are best off using the guid - as shown in the wiki: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/razor-edit.toolbar#multiple-entities-prefil